# Passing multiple arguments to a function?

Tags: python

I am trying to do an operation like the one below:

```
a = 2
b = 4
c = 6

def my_function(a,b,c):
    a1 = a*2
    b1 = b*2
    c1 = c*2
    return (a1,b1,c1)

x = my_function(a,b,c)

my_function(x)
```

Where I would like to call `my_function()` iteratively on its own output if it meets a certain condition.

However, I get the result:

```
TypeError: my_function() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'b' and 'c'
```

I am sure this is a basic question and has been answered elsewhere, but it seems so simple that it is difficult to search for.

Comment: use `my_function(*x)` which makes the `x`-tuple *explode* and create as many inputs as elements it contained.

Comment: `my_function(*x)` -- see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the "star args" syntax.

```
my_function(*x)
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/7007605) for more.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I knew it would be something simple!

Answer (score 5):

use `*` to Unpack tuple so that all elements of it can be passed as different parameters.

```
my_function(*x)
```